# High memory usage with Python and sentry-sdk

Tags: python, sentry

In my code in Python v3.9, recently I've made the integration with Sentry, using the following version sentry-sdk==1.9.0. In the beginning, the Sentry was receiving a lot of unwanted 404 HTTP messages (20k/day). So I did some changes in my code, putting the before_send function to filter these kind of messages, like below:

```
def before_send(event, hint):
    if 'exc_info' in hint:
        exc_type, exc_value, tb = hint['exc_info']

        if isinstance(exc_value, (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, InconsistentDeal)):
            if "404 Client Error: Not Found" in str(exc_value)
                return None

        elif isinstance(exc_value, (PaymentNotFound)):
            return None

    return event

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=config.SENTRY_DSN,
    integrations=[CeleryIntegration()],
    before_send=before_send,
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
)
```

After that, the quantity of messages arriving in Sentry reduced almost 95%, but another problem's appeared. My application has been draining a lot of memory and I'm sure is the Sentry, because when I took off the code, the application consumed the standard amount of memory. How can I solve this problem?

I tried to minimize the traces_sample_rate just to test, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Reading the Sentry code, I see that it records the fact that an event was never sent, and this only happens if before_send() drops the event. Could you try setting `send_client_reports=False` inside `sentry_sdk.init()` , and see if the memory leak improves? [Docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/options/#send-client-reports)

Comment: This is not a great solution, but there's a way to keep the memory leak under control, even if you can't fix it. There's an option to gunicorn which restarts the worker process every N requests, which would reset the memory use. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#max-requests (See also max-requests-jitter.)

Comment: @NickODell i've tested using the property you mentioned and the memory leak still went up. Do you have any suggestion on how I could improve the code and avoid this memory leak?

Comment: Two ideas for narrowing down the cause of the leak: 1) Test a before_send() which always returns `event`. This checks if the mere presence of the hook has an effect, or if it's something about this code. 2) Test a before_send() which always returns `None`. This checks if it's dropping the event which causes the leak.